# check if specific row exists mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysqli query which fetches all the images from the table(I have 5 images that I display). I am using a jquery slider to display them. The problem is if there are no 5 images I see blank page like if the user uploads just two images then the rest three thumbnails will be empty and when you click on them it shows empty area. I don't want that happen so how do I only show the thumbnail if the image exists instead of showing empty thumbnail?

I tried the below but this doesn't work. I just need to see if image_one exists then show the thumbnail and the same for the rest of the images.

```
<?php
 $stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where title = ? AND id = ? limit 1 ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $title, $id);
$stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$path = 'images/';
?>


<div id="slides">

<?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?><div class="slide"><a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $path.$row['image_one']?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img class="cloudzoom appsld" src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_one']?>"/></a></div><?php };?>
<?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?><div class="slide"><a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $path.$row['image_two']?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img class="cloudzoom appsld" src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_two']?>"/></a></div><?php };?>
<?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?> <div class="slide"><a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $path.$row['image_three']?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img class="cloudzoom appsld" src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_three']?>"/></a></div><?php };?>
<?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?><div class="slide"><a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $path.$row['image_four']?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img class="cloudzoom appsld" src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_four']?>"/></a></div><?php };?>
<?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?><div class="slide"><a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $path.$row['image_five']?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img class="cloudzoom appsld" src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_five']?>"/></a></div><?php };?>

</div>

<div id="slide_menu">

<ul id="slide"> <!-- This is the thumbnail area -->
    <li class="fbar">&nbsp;</li>
    <?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?><li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_one']?>"  /></a></li><?php }; ?>
    <?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?><li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_two']?>"  /></a></li><?php }; ?>
    <?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?><li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_three']?>"  /></a></li><?php }; ?>
    <?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?><li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_four']?>"  /></a></li><?php }; ?>
    <?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?><li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_five']?>"  /></a></li><?php }; ?>
</ul>


</div>
```

Comment: Look into using loops, so it won't matter how many or how few you have it will only display what is in the database.

Comment: how I do that? I have no idea.

Comment: You've violated the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) by having columns named "one", "two" and so on. There is no such thing as "two" in a [properly normalized database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). They call it a "one-to-many" relationship, not a "one-to-five".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can not see your database design so look at your default value for

`image_one` and so on

The row count is allways `0` or `1` (because of `Limit 1`)
Important are the fields `image_one` to `image_five` 
These fields are always present, regardless of whether they are empty or with file names are filled.

depending on the default value test it

for example one of

- if ($row['image_one'] > '') {
- if ($row['image_one'] > null {

put an `if` arround building html.

```
<?php if($result->num_rows > 0){?>
 <?php if ($row['image_one'] > '') 
   {?>
     <li class="menuItem">
     <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_one']?>" /></a>
     </li>
   <?php 
   }?>
    .... next 4 other tests
 <?php if ($row['image_two'] > '') 
    ....

<?php } // END__$result->num_rows > 0 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
   ...
    <ul id="slide"> <!-- This is the thumbnail area -->
        <li class="fbar">&nbsp;</li>
        <?php
        foreach ( $row as $element => $val){
          if(isset($val)) {
            print "<li class='menuItem'><a href=''><img src=".$path.$val."/></a></li>";
          }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
...
```

and the same for the 1st (`<div id="slides">`) block

Comment: It's not that easy . As you can see : `SELECT * FROM table where title = ? AND id = ?` . There's more database fields, not just the imagefile name fields. with your solution all of these fields are also decorated with a nice `<img` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Im not 100% sure for pdo but its not too far away

```
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table where title = $title AND id = $id limit 1 ";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<div class="slide">
   <a class="fancybox" href="images/<?php echo $row['DB-IMAGE-PATH-HERE']; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery">
      <img class="cloudzoom appsld" src="images/<?php echo $row['DB-IMAGE-PATH-HERE']; ?>"/>
   </a>
</div>

<?php } // end while loop ?>
</div> <!-- end id="slides" -->
```

Comment: does this hide the li tag if the image doesn't exist? I don't want the

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {` . It looks like you've misunderstood the problem somewhat. I'm sure you wanted to iterate over the database fields, not over the database records. Of which there are either `0` or only `1` .